# Stochastic process with a property that plotting his realizations "look the same" in any time interval

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, time-series

I have an interesting, though not very well formulated question. Does there exist non-trivial time series stochastic model, fulfilling that his plot "looks the same" in any time interval?

More descripting: Let $(X_t, t\in\mathbb{R})$ be stochastic process (which I am interested in).  Look at his realizations on [0,1], and realizations on [0,1000]. Draw their plots without axis. Then it is not possible to distinguish if the realization is on time interval [0,1] or on [0,1000].

For example, if we have standard brownian motion, it is easy to distinguish this because there will be much smaller dependence between close variables on [0,1000] than on [0,1]. In other words, graph will look "more jumpy" on [0,1000].

I suppose the model will need to have heavy tails, but it is only my intuition. Does such model exist?

Comment: Even if your question is - as you say yourself - not very precise, it does make a lot of sense and can be made precise. One remark though: when you say "plot without the axis", what axis would you like "not to show its values"? Just the time axis (x-axis) or both time and space axis (both x and y)? In the latter case, I would say also Brownian Motions do satisfy your property.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. Well, if you "do not plot" only x-axis, you can distinguish the time intervals e.g. from the maximal value- the maximum on [0,1] will be much smaller than on [0,1000]. I mean, i dont see why the brownian motion satisfy the property (property with both axis erased). Consider that we know the exact model- variance of BM is one. Then plot on [0,1000] will have seemingly "larger variance" than the one on [0,1]. We know exact model, not only the family of models- does it make sense?

Comment: i meant the following: if you "do not plot" the x-axis only, you ll definitely be able to distinguish bw [0,1] and [0,1000]. But if you do not plot both x and y aixs, then you will NOT be able to distinguish. Do you agree?

Comment: I do not agree actually. At least if we still talk about Brownian motion. What you wrote is exactly the property I want to achieve, but why do you think that for BM it is not possible? Maybe we still understand the question a bit differently

Comment: Well - if you delete labels on both x and y axis, how can you distinguish the two?

Comment: Okey, I tried to draw two plots of BM on different intervals and it looks like you are right-you can not distinguish them. For some reason, my intuition was that when I have interval [0,n] then for $n\to\infty$ the plot will look as a realization of white noise, but that was very wrong. 

Therefore, the question is solved because yes BM actually fulfill such property. If we erase only y-axis, then we can distinguish between intervals [0,1] and [0,1000] because, well, we have it written on the x-axis. 

Sorry for not such an interesting problem

Comment: I disagree on the fact that the problem was not interesting! In fact I think it s very deep and fascinating: it s basically the concept of self-similarity that you were trying to make precise. I just kept commenting and not giving an answer because it was not clear to me if you were just looking for the existence of self-similar problems or really the existence of self-similar processes with $H=0$. These terms will become clear once i sketch a little answer for you hopefully soon.

Comment: Of course, the problem by itself can be surely very interesting... I was indeed looking for existence and example of such self-similar process. And this is not interesting because trivially BM fulfills it. 

Maybe my other question now is, if some ARMA process with iid noise (alpha-stable noise without finite variance?) can posses this property. But as I actually started to read about "self-similiar processes" as you suggested, it looks like such answer is no, although I am not sure. But the theory concerning that is indeed interesting.